# managed property Name

Tags: managed-metadata, managed-property, display-name

In sharepoint 2010, there are the default metadate "Name"
I'm trying to make a search on with Name:'test' but it doesn't work.

What is the name of this managed property?
If i've to create one with which crawled property?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Finally i found the solution.
I've created a managed proprty linked to "ows_LinkFilename"

Comment: Please add that as an answer to your question instead. That way you will later be able to mark it as your accepted answer, and the question will show as resolved